# SMS Permissions

Tags: android, permissions, sms, permission-denied

I am building an Android app via android studio. One major feature of the app is sending SMS but I cannot seem to get it to run correctly on different devices due to permission errors.I tried to eliminate this issue by prompting for permissions when the user logs in  but this worked on API version 13 and failed on 26,I tried it with `build.versioncode.o.` but his also failed.
What is the correct way to do this and to check permissions each time a SMS is sent?(note sms are sent from many different functions throughout the app.

I also just got this error hen sending message

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10205 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
```

Request permission on log in

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
private void getPermissionToReadSMS() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please allow permission!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},
                REQUEST_READ_SMS);
    }
}
```

Method snippet that sends method

```
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(testContact.getNumber(), null, "SENT MESSAGE" + message, sentPending, deliveredPending);
```

App Manifest

```
 <!-- grant permission to uses in build sms service -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission-group.SMS" />
```

Comment: use @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)

Comment: Why lollypop and what does that exactly do? Ive been trying to get a better understanding. Does that specify the min level or what ?

Comment: add this  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> in manifest

Comment: during lollipop has started that permission things

Comment: @AbhinavGupta Marshmallow.

Comment: @MikeM. yes sorry Marshmallow

Comment: @krishankTripathi [`SmsManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager) is not deprecated.

Comment: pardon me i though he was using android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager

Answer (score 2):

For checkPermission to send SMS, you will need to add 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />` 
permission and the below code for >=23 api

```
 protected void sendSMS() {
     if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
             Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
             != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                   Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
                } else {
                   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                      new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                      PERMISSION_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
                }
          }
}
 @Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
      switch (requestCode) {
         case PERMISSION_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
               && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                  SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                  smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent successfully.", 
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                  "SMS faild", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               return;
            }
         }
      }

   }
```

Comment: how would i verify >=23?

Comment: add if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)

Answer (score 1):

```
 //You should declare this in your project
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {

            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_SMS,
            Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,

    };
```

//and call verifymethod where you want 
      verifyStoragePermissions(Activity_home.this);

```
//and the verifyStoragePermissions methode is  
 public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
        int readPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        int smspermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
        int smspermission1 = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS);
        int smssendpermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);

        if (readPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || readPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || smspermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || smspermission1 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  || smssendpermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {userActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sending it from a fragment. The solution given by @Android Team above works for me for the first time only. Apparently if the app has required permission it doesnt call onRequestPermissionsResult.

Using the following code (else portion with log msg "Have permission.." in the onlclick handler is required for my app to work). I'm using Android 11 device.

```
       if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
        } else {
            //ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
            requestPermissions(
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
        }
    } else {
        Log.i("smsB", "Have permission... send the sms now");
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "SMS sent.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```